# Chrome webdriver in selenium wont connect to proxy

Tags: python, selenium, ssh-tunnel, chrome-web-driver

I've bound port 3003 on my local machine to a remote server

`ssh user@remoteserver -D 3003`

And in my python script

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:3003")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

When I run the script, I get no error, chrome launches and I fail to load google.com. Shouldn't this script be making requests through 127.0.0.1:3003?

The ssh tunnel is good. If I manually set a proxy in my browser to 127.0.0.1:3003, requests go through my remote server.
Where am I going wrong in this script?

Answer (score 1):

per @Shawn Spitz's comment on [Setting a proxy for Chrome Driver in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730306/setting-a-proxy-for-chrome-driver-in-selenium)
one needs to use socks5// for this because its a socks proxy. I had http, so
    chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:3003")