# Setting proxy settings for Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to authenticate against a proxy server using a domain, username and password before my selenium tests will run when executed by our build server.

I know about the Proxy object, but I'm unsure how to set the HttpProxy property correctly.

When run by our build server, I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"3372.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
(Session info: Opera with embedded Chromium 54.0.2840.87)
(Driver info: OperaDriver=0.2.0 (ba47709ed9e35ce26dbd960fb5d75be104290d96),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (33)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack Trace:
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver..ctor(OperaDriverService service, OperaOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver..ctor(String operaDriverDirectory, OperaOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Opera.OperaDriver..ctor(String operaDriverDirectory, OperaOptions options)
```

I've tried using netsh winhttp to set proxy settings at the system level but this doesn't appear to have made a difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a proxy for Chrome Driver in Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730306/setting-a-proxy-for-chrome-driver-in-selenium)

Comment: Do you need only the webdriver's session to be with that proxy or do you need to authenticate against that server once before the tests?

Comment: I need to authenticate against the server once before the tests. My development environment does not have direct access to the Internet so I must go through an authenticated proxy (out of my control unfortunately)