# Headless Chrome (with selenium) CANNOT request with PROXY server, but requests can?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to use Chrome along with python webdriver + selenium, but it seems not working when I set the proxy settings? Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = 'http://42.115.88.220:53281'
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chromeOptions.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")

wbe = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
wbe.get("http://icanhazip.com")
```

When I run the above codes, the browser gives me: "This site can’t be reached" error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The connection was reset. 
>   Try:
>
> - Checking the connection
> - Checking the proxy and the firewall
> - Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

**Some Efforts:** I tried [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) with my proxy server, and it works. So it shouldn't be the problem of my proxy server.

```
import requests

proxies = {"http": "http://42.115.88.220:53281"}
r = requests.get("http://icanhazip.com", proxies = proxies)
print (r.status_code)
```

This gives me a response code of 200 and good response.

**Goal:** My final goal is to build a web-crawler with headless chrome with PROXY, so now I am testing a non-headless one first. But it seems there have been something wrong with this PROXY issue.

I would be really appreciated if anyone could help me out with this problem!!!

Comment: Does changing `ignore-certificate-errors` to `--ignore-certificate-errors` have any effect?

Comment: Please follow the below link that i have shared

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730306/setting-a-proxy-for-chrome-driver-in-selenium

Comment: https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy/issues/193

Comment: @cullzie no, there's not. It is not working even when I removes '--ignore-certificate-errors' parameter

Comment: @akshaypatil I tried what you've shared, and they are not working still...But anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
For me it seems that you have used wrong type of headless mode. For chrome selenium browsers it's important to set --headless argument correct.

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = 'http://ip:port'
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY) 
chromeOptions.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
# Headless mode for chrome browser
chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless=chrome')
wbe = webdriver.Chrome('your_driver_path_or_service', options=chromeOptions) 
wbe.get("http://icanhazip.com")
print(wbe.title)
print(wbe.current_url)
print(wbe.page_source)

# Output:
# http://icanhazip.com/
# <html><head><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"></head><body><pre 
# style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">your ip
# </pre></body></html>
```