# C# Setting a proxy Id Pass Login for Chrome Driver in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, proxy

I have been struggling for 1 week, I couldn't succeed.

C# Selenium Chrome Proxy ID and Pass. I couldn't log in.

Vis. S. 2017 I am using  Can you give information as a guide or can be a video source

Comment: Ca you add more details on how are you using the C# Selenium Proxy, example of the code you are using and also detail a bit more of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: IWebDriver driver1;
                        ChromeDriverService cds = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                            cds.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                        ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();

                            var ch = new ChromeOptions();

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy))
                            {
                                co.AddArgument("--proxy-server=" + proxy);
                            }
C# Selenium Chrome Proxy ID and Pass. I couldn't log in.

Comment: I think maybe this topic can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730306/setting-a-proxy-for-chrome-driver-in-selenium

Comment: I think maybe this topic can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730306/setting-a-proxy-for-chrome-driver-in-selenium