# Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is Selenium using C# Code .

Code Which I am using:

Here is The code

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1200");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-logging");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--log-level=1");

//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmWmCw_8WsE

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("./", chromeOptions);


driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
var url = "";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

I need help how i can fech the post in the network and fetch the signature in the request body.

Fetch The data:

[image: Fetch The data]

Thanks

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Coded added in the question please check it

Answer (score 0):

You should use a proxy to detect network requests. Here is a popular Java one: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy

For C# look at answers like these to setup proxies:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35167823/1387701

Comment: No man, I have to fetch the network the url and then fetch the body .

Comment: Thats what proxies do.