# How to use Proxy with Username and Password in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, proxy-authentication

I'm having a problem when using Proxy with Selenium in C#.

My proxy requires a Username and Password to authenticate to use it with Chrome Selenium C#.

**Is there anyway to authenticate proxy with authentication?**

<sub>Thanks so much, English is my 2nd language.</sub>

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730306/setting-a-proxy-for-chrome-driver-in-selenium